# Postman - How can I pass variables to my GET query?

Tags: api, url, parameter-passing, postman

I am trying to pass a variable in my postman GET query but I'm having troubles figuring out how to do this.

What I am trying to do here is I have a request e.g:

```
https://test.com&q=(account+eq+"123456")
```

and I'm trying to pass that `123456` value as variable that I can quickly modify. I'm not clear on where to do this however. I tried setting a variable

e.g : `https://test.com&q=(account+eq+{{var}})` and then setting that value under Query Params: in a key value.

But I'm not sure if this is allowed or how I can do this in Postman.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIiIm.png)

Comment: what error you getting after you tried `https://test.com&q=(account+eq+{{var}})`  this?

Comment: I am getting an unresolved variable. I am defining the variable under my Query Params: Key|Value so it would be var|"123456"

Comment: have you set that variable as with any particular scope?

Comment: Scope as in environment and global scope? No i was hoping i wouldnt have to set it there. 

I actually tried setting it in environment and that worked.

Would this be the fastest way to do what i'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: Better question is there a way i can set these environment variables in the body via raw text?

Comment: yes, there are following 3 variable scopes - 1- Environment - limited to your environment,  2 - Global  - this variables you can use across environments, 3- local variables -  limited to test case,

Comment: same way as you used in url

Comment: thanks i have the info to go foward!